# cURL with PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json, post, curl

I wish to mimic, using CURL with PHP, the operation of a website that retrieves data using an AJAX POST.

Normally when I'm viewing POST requests using Firebug you will see variable/value pairs, but in this case all you see is a single JSON string. E.g.

```
{"refId":"14536"}
```

Is there a way to mimic this request using CURL? I've looked at CURL but as far as I can see the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS parameter has to be a query string made up of one or more name/value.

Here is my test code with a normal POST request using a single name/value pair. I'd like to modify it to do the above.

```
$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3",
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 600,      // timeout on connect
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 600,      // timeout on response
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => 'var1=113',
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://localhost/t4.php"
);

$curlCh      = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curlCh, $curlOptions );
$fileContents = curl_exec( $curlCh );
$curlErr     = curl_errno( $curlCh );
$curlErrmsg  = curl_error( $curlCh );

if( $curlErr ) echo "CURL ERROR:</b> $curlErr  $curlErrmsg";
echo $fileContents; //check worked
curl_close( $curlCh );
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this asynchronously from within an already loaded page?  If what you mean is to *literally* mimic ajax, you will need to use Javascript AJAX to create the client side interaction.  Server side script will not be able to swap on demand DOM elements without refreshing the page.

Comment: @DeaconDesperado. No, I just want to get CURL to return the same data as the AJAX does.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$postData = json_encode(array('refId' => '14536'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

Comment: In order to make this key value pair in json, you must instead use syntax json_encode(array('refId'=>'14536));  This sets up the associative relation rather than two separate array items.

Comment: His example was: "{"refId","14536"}", which is not a key-value pair, but two separate entries in a dictionary.

Comment: @sagi, @DeaconDesperado. My mistake. I meant to say {"refId":"14536"}. I've updated the question.

Comment: @sagi, @DeaconDesperado Have tried the suggestion. Still doesnt work. I'm going to try and find some utility to log whats getting sent to and from curl

Comment: You can see what get's sent from curl by setting the CURLOPT_VERBOSE option: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

Comment: @sagi. Thanks for this. However I was really looking for something that prints out the data getting sent to and from curl - my query variable 'var1' does not appear in the CURLOPT_VERBOSE output (it just seems to print out stuff about the user agent, host etc).